# Converse to Taylor's theorem in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

So I have been following a book and understand the following version of Taylor's theorem:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a separable Banach space, $A \subset X$ open and convex, $f\in C^n(A, Y)$ and $x_0 \in A$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(x_0 + h) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} D^k f(x_0)(h, \dots, h) + o(\|h\|^n)\\ \text{ as } h \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}

Now I would like to know whether or not the following is true:

If for each $x_0 \in A$, there exist bounded multilinear maps $D_k(x_0):X^k \rightarrow Y$ such that $$f(x_0 + h) = \sum_{k=0}^n D_k(x_0)(h, \dots, h) + o(\|h\|^n)  \text{ as } h \rightarrow 0$$ then $f \in C^n(A,Y)$ and $D^kf(x_0)(h, \dots, h) = k! D_k(x_0)(h, \dots, h)$

Essentially, I am wondering how to make the follwing observation formal: If $f(x) = \langle x,x  \rangle$, then
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) 
&= \langle x,x  \rangle +   + 2\langle x,h  \rangle + \langle h,h  \rangle\\
&= f(x) + Df(x)(h) + \frac{1}{2}D^2f(x)(h,h)
\end{align*}

I'm guessing this is true since Gelfand and Fomin's book takes this as the definition of 2nd order differentiability, but I am pretty stuck on how to show it. Showing Taylor's theorem was hard enough because the proof I saw used a slick calculus trick. Are there any recommended references with this converse?

Comment: What is $X$?$\,\,$

Comment: @Gary sorry, $X$ is a Banach space

Comment: Let's do a sanity check. Pick $X=A=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $n=1$. Then you say, given $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a constant $c(x_0)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+c(x_0)h.$$ Thus, this gives you differentiability, but not $f\in C^1$. So for your statement to have a chance, you want the $D_k$ to depend continuously on $x_0$.